# Verifying event registration using Moq

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I'm developing an asp.net (classic) application trying to implement the MVP pattern [using this example](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/09/ASP.NETSupervisingControllerModelViewPresenterFromSchematicToUnitTestsToCode.aspx). In trying to unit test my presenter and using the following pattern, the psuedocode for which looks like so

```
//base view interface
public interface IView
{
    event EventHandler Init;

    event EventHandler Load;

    bool IsPostBack { get; }

    void DataBind();

    bool IsValid { get;}
}

//presenter psuedo code
public class SomePresenter
{
     public SomePresenter(ISomeDomainService service, IView someView)
     {
           ...
           //HOW DO WE TEST/VERIFY THAT THIS REGISTRATION OCCURS?
           someView.Init += OnInit;
           someView.Load += OnLoad;
     }
}
...
//consuming code that exercises the above code, that needs to be tested
var presenter = new SomePresenter(someDomainService, someView);
```

How do I verify that the presenter is doing what is expected i.e. registering for the Init and Load events? While this is easily done in the [Phil Haack's example](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/09/ASP.NETSupervisingControllerModelViewPresenterFromSchematicToUnitTestsToCode.aspx) using Rhino mocks...

```
[Test]
public void VerifyAttachesToViewEvents()
{
    viewMock.Load += null;
    LastCall.IgnoreArguments();
    viewMock.PostSaved += null;
    LastCall.IgnoreArguments();
    mocks.ReplayAll();
    new PostEditController(viewMock, 
      this.dataServiceMock);
    mocks.VerifyAll();
}
```

... how can we do this using MOQ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would appear that this functionality is [not currently available](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=100) in moq, but may appear in a future version (I had a look in the 4.0.812.4 beta, but it doesn't seem to be there).

It may be worth asking the question, "why does `SomePresenter` need to subscribe to the View's `Load` and `Init` events?" Presumably it is because the `SomePresenter` class needs to respond to those events. So it might be better to use the `Raise` method on your `Mock<IView>` to raise the `Load` and `Init` events, and then assert that `SomePresenter` did the right thing in response to them.

Comment: I thought about that, essentially there are two parts to testing this piece of code. 
1. Interaction testing... that verifies event registration
2. State based testing... which verifies that the event handler in the presenter behaves as expected.
The clean unit test would be to test each of those cases separately. 
One solution for (1) is to add a couple of methods to the IView interface

public interface IView
{
  ...
  public void RegisterForInit(EventHandler callback);
  ...
}

and modify the presenter constructor to

public SomePresenter(...)
{
   ...
   someView.RegisterFoInit(OnInit);
}

Comment: and it follows that you can't use Strict Mocks from MOQ if there are event subscriptions involved. (groan)

Comment: Updated link to the GitHub issue https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/49 regarding this concern.

Answer (score 48):

The **`moq 4.13`** introduced this feature. Now it is possible to verify if `add\remove` has been invoked. Therefore four new methods have been introduced:

1. `SetupAdd`
2. `SetupRemove`
3. `VerifyAdd`
4. `VerifyRemove`

**Example**

```
var mock = new Mock<IAdder<EventArgs>>();
mock.SetupAdd(m => m.Added += (sender, args) => { });

mock.Object.Added += (sender, args) => { };
mock.Object.Added += (sender, args) => { };

mock.VerifyAdd(m => m.Added += It.IsAny<EventHandler>(), Times.Exactly(2));
```

---

**NB:** Notice that in order to verify at least one setup should be added. The reason is to keep backward compatibility with the older version of **`moq`**.

Comment: In addition your last note, from version `4.15.1`, we don't need the `SetupAdd`, we can use only the `Verify`

Answer (score 3):

I know it's maybe too late for #Dilip, but this answer can be helpful for those who are trying to do the same.
Here is the test class

```
public delegate void SubscriptionHandler<T>(string name, T handler);

public class SomePresenterTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Subscription_Test()
    {
        var someServiceMock = new Mock<ISomeDomainService>();
        var viewMock = new Mock<IView>();
        //Setup your viewMock here

        var someView = new FakeView(viewMock.Object);
        EventHandler initHandler = null;            
        someView.Subscription += (n, h) => { if ((nameof(someView.Init)).Equals(n)) initHandler=h; };

        Assert.IsNull(initHandler);

        var presenter = new SomePresenter(someServiceMock.Object, someView);

        Assert.IsNotNull(initHandler);
        Assert.AreEqual("OnInit", initHandler.Method?.Name);
    }
}
```

**FakeView** is a decorator implemented as follow (pay attention to Events:Init/Load{add;remove}):

```
public class FakeView : IView
{
    public event SubscriptionHandler<EventHandler> Subscription;
    public event SubscriptionHandler<EventHandler> Unsubscription;
    private IView _view;
    public FakeView(IView view)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(view);
        _view = view;
    }

    public bool IsPostBack => _view.IsPostBack;
    public bool IsValid => _view.IsValid;

    public event EventHandler Init
    {
        add
        {
            Subscription?.Invoke(nameof(Init), value);
            _view.Init += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            Unsubscription?.Invoke(nameof(Init), value);
            _view.Init -= value;
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler Load
    {

        add
        {
            Subscription?.Invoke(nameof(Load), value);
            _view.Init += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            Unsubscription?.Invoke(nameof(Load), value);
            _view.Init -= value;
        }
    }

    public void DataBind()
    {
        _view.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I spent some time with this question and the solution which I'm using in my project is:

**Unit test:**

```
// Arrange
TestedObject.Setup(x => x.OnEvent1());
TestedObject.Setup(x => x.OnEvent2());

// Act
TestedObject.Object.SubscribeEvents();
TestedObject.Raise(x => x.Event1 += null);
TestedObject.Raise(x => x.Event2 += null);

// Assert
TestedObject.Verify(x => x.OnEvent1(), Times.Once());
TestedObject.Verify(x => x.OnEvent2(), Times.Once());
```

**Tested method:**

```
this.Event1 += OnEvent1;
this.Event2 += OnEvent2;
```

So, first you have to mock the methods which you will assign the events, after you call the method which you want to test, and finally raise all subscribed events. If the event is really subscribed, you can check with Moq if the assigned method is called.

GLHF!

Comment: This is confusing though. OnEvent1() method is on the object under test, while Raise() needs to be called on the mocked object. Can you post actual working code with all classes shown?

Comment: @Guilherme Moschen - this code is not clear and confusing