# How can I unit test subscribing to events?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following method:

```
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        SpinnerService.OnShow += ShowSpinner;
        SpinnerService.OnHide += HideSpinner;
    }



    event Action OnShow;
    event Action OnHide;
```

How can I test that the OnShow event is subscribed to ShowSpinner ?

I am using a mock with Moq for SpinnerService.

Comment: The adding of the event handler is an implementation detail that you shouldn't be testing.  You should be testing that the spinner shows or is hidden when it's supposed to be shown or hidden, without caring how that is accomplished by whatever is responsible for doing that.

Comment: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#events

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58008626/3311799